# pexpect , handeling child process

Tags: python, heroku-postgres, pexpect, os.system

i am trying to automate data logging to postgres database hosted oh heroku account.

```
import pexpect
import os
import sys
from time import sleep

#os.system("heroku login -i")
child = pexpect.spawn ('heroku login -i')
child.expect ('Email .*:')
child.sendline ('har**********@gmail.com')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline ('js4*********SZq')
child.close(force=True)
#child.send('\r')
sleep(0.5)
child2 = pexpect.spawn ('heroku pg:psql postgresql-globular-95641 --app overal-vehicle')
child2.expect ('overal-vehicle::DATABASE=>')
child2.send ('SELECT version();')
child2.send('\r')
```

#after this part i would also like to add some sql queries, but i am not able to login, its just telling invalid credentials, and to login via browser.

this is what i want to achive[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL1Wp.png)

when i try manualy, all the commands do work,
i was wondering what could be the issue, or there is some way that heroku detects this is an automated task, and fails the login

Please someone tell me what is the issue,

Answer (score 1):

You have to go old-school Pexpect and send only a carriage return (`\r`) when entering the password:

> **NOTE** - Using Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("heroku login -i")
child.delaybeforesend = 0.5
child.expect_exact("Email:")
child.sendline("har**********@gmail.com\r")
child.expect_exact('Password:')

# ojo!
child.send("js4*********SZq")
child.send("\r")

index = child.expect_exact(["Logged in as", pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT, ])
if index != 0:
    print("Could not log into Heroku.")
# The child is closed implicitly when command is complete, but I add this anyway
child.close()
print("Logged in!")

child = pexpect.spawn("heroku auth:whoami")
index = child.expect_exact(["Error: not logged in", "har**********@gmail.com", ])
if index == 0:
    print("Login failed!")
    exit()
child.close()
print("heroku auth:whoami: {0}".format(child.match.decode()))

child = pexpect.spawn("heroku logout")
child.expect_exact("Logging out... done")
child.close()
print("{0}".format(child.match.decode()))
```

**Output**

```
Logged in!
heroku auth:whoami: har**********@gmail.com
Logging out... done
```

Good luck coding!